# Windows 7 Hiberate Returns to Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hibernate

I recently dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu and Windows 7. Whenever I close the top of my laptop while in Windows it goes to hibernate, however it returns back to the Ubuntu log in screen. Grub doesn't even show up to allow me to choose which system to boot back to. 
How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What is your default OS in GRUB? A strange problem that may not have a resolution due to the nature of hibernate. Hibernate saves to disk and shuts down in a particular state. Unsure "why", though. I would start by setting Windows to be the default OS in GRUB and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I believe Ubuntu is. How do I change it to Windows?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you reboot from the ubuntu screen and select windows in grub, you will (probably) get the pre-hibernation state.
2. If you make windows your default OS in grub, you will probably replace the "hibernate in windows -> wake up in ubuntu" problem with "hibernate in ubuntu -> wake up in windows" one.

Comment: Where do I go to make windows my default OS in grub?

Comment: Cheers sds lol! Either way the user is going to be stuffed!